# Integral representation of $\frac{355}{113}-\pi$?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

It is well known that
$$
\frac{22}{7} - \pi = \int_0^1 (x-x^2)^4 \frac{dx}{1+x^2},
$$

Given that $\frac{355}{113}$ is an excellent approximation of $\pi$, is there any known integral representation of $\frac{355}{113}-\pi$, in which the integrand is obviously non-negative?

Comment: S.K. Lucas, Integral proofs that $355/113>\pi$, *Gazette Aust. Math. Soc.* **32** (2005) 263-266.  From MathSciNet: "No simple and elegant result was found."

Comment: My favorite from the paper Gerald linked is $$\frac{355}{113}-\pi = \int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25+816x^2)}{3164(1+x^2)}dx.$$

Comment: @mathworker21 ... that is also quoted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/860499/44

Comment: $355/113$ is not just an "excellent approximation"; it is, like $22/7,$ one of the convergents in the continued fraction representation of $\pi.$ And it differse from $\pi$ by less than the reciprocal of the square of the denominator; thus by less than $1/113^2. \qquad$

Comment: Link to a pdf of the article @Gerald cited http://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/resource/general/Lucas.pdf

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments by [Gerald Edgar](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425468/integral-representation-of-frac355113-pi#comment1093606_425468) and [mathworker21](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425468/integral-representation-of-frac355113-pi#comment1093607_425468), some formulas are given in a paper by S. K. Lucas, [Integral proofs that $355/113>π$](https://web.archive.org/web/20200824045610/https://www.austms.org.au/wp-content/uploads/Gazette/2005/Sep05/), *Gazette Aust. Math. Soc.* **32** (2005), 263–266.
(See also the author's 2009 *Amer. Math. Monthly* paper, [Approximations to $π$ Derived from Integrals with Nonnegative Integrands](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642693).)
One such formula is

$$\frac{355}{113} - \pi = \int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25+816x^2)}{3164(1+x^2)}\, dx.$$

Comment: No doubt your intention was to bring deserved attention to mathworker21's comment, but I think it would be more appropriate to first suggest to him or to Gerald Edgar to make it into an answer.

Comment: The moderators have now made this answer community wiki, which should address the issue that the author of the answer is different from the author of the comment.